# Arraybuffer : I want to play the audio from an arraybuffer using decodeAudioData in angular

Tags: angular, audio, arraybuffer

Hi My problem is  I want to decode the arraybuffer which received over an HTTP method in order to play it in the browser my problem plz take a look to the code i will try to explain more .

```
    ngOnInit() {
      // this service returns the arraybuffer and I successfully get it .
        this.radioService.generateVoiceMethode().subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res);  // display the array in the console 
            this.audioArray = new ArrayBuffer(res.byteLength);
            this.audioArray = res;


               console.log(this.audioArray); // display in the console with scucess 
// my problem is the data in this  audioArray  no longer exists when I  try to 
     // decode it in another method 

            });

        }




 playAudio() {

    console.log(this.audioArray); // this display empty arraybuffer !! 

    this.context.decodeAudioData(this.audioArray).then((buffer)=>{
        this.buf = buffer;
        this.play();
    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error); /// error is : DOMException: Unable to decode audio data
    });



 }
```

Comment: Are you calling `playAudio()` after the audioArray has been set?

Comment: yes playAudio is when i click a button .

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're calling `playAudio` before `radioService.generateVoiceMethode()` has had a chance to get a response and populate `audioArray`

With a little restructuring;

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.radioService.generateVoiceMethode().subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);  // display the array in the console 
        this.audioArray = new ArrayBuffer(res.byteLength);
        this.audioArray = res;
           console.log(this.audioArray);
           this.playAudio(this.audioArray);
        });
}

playAudio(audioArray) {
    console.log(audioArray); // this display empty arraybuffer !! 

    this.context.decodeAudioData(audioArray).then((buffer)=>{
    this.buf = buffer;
        this.play();
    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error); /// error is : DOMException: Unable to decode audio data
    });
}
```

This ensures that you're calling the `playAudio()` method after the data has been set.

Alternatively, you could opt in to use the observable pattern to kick off the playAudio method as well

Comment: thank u for ur answer but , no when i try your sol even the res is empty this time :(

Comment: If you'd like you can throw it in https://stackblitz.com/ and I can help you troubleshoot this :)